# AngularJS directive and validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, directive

I'm new here :)

Ok I have problem, I wrote the script like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.directive('formInput', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: ['^form'],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctr)
        {

            var form = ctr[0];
            var newEl = '<div class="control-group">' +
                    '<div class="controls">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="' + attrs.formId + '" name="' + attrs.formId + '" required>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<span ng-show="' + form.$name + '.' + attrs.formId + '.$error.required" class="help-block">Can\'t be blank</span>';

            element.replaceWith(newEl);
        }
    }
});
```

and this html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <form name="test321" novalidate>
        <form-input required form-id="iddd" label="test"></form-input>
    </form>
</div>
```

Im trying to get dynamic input but validation dosen't working, any one can help me please?

live link: http://jsfiddle.net/x9yuua94/